# XeLaTeX fontspec on Fedora 20

Tags: xetex, fontspec, linux

It's not recognizing `\setmainfont` as a command, if I understand this right.

I switched to XeTeX from PDFTeX so I could use an OTF file on my system. This works no problem on my OS X 10.10 machine through MacPorts, but I've encountered a host of errors on Fedora 20.

I'm working through them one by one. So far it's been a matter of finding and installing all the packages with `yum`, but I already have the latest version of `texlive-fontspec` and I'm out of ideas for this one.

Download [this](https://www.theleagueofmoveabletype.com/sorts-mill-goudy) for MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=5.5in,paperheight=8.75in,left=1in,top=1in,right=0.75in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{sorts_mill_goudy.otf}[ ItalicFont = sorts_mill_goudy-italic.otf, BoldFont = texgyrepagella-bold.otf ]
\newfontfamily{\linenums}[Numbers=Lining]{sorts_mill_goudy.otf}
\begin{document}
testing Testing \textsc{testing Testing} 0123456789 \linenums{0123456789}
\end{document}
```

Error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.4 \setmainfont{sorts_mill_goudy.otf}[
                                        ItalicFont = sorts_mill_goudy-italic...

? H
You're in trouble here.  Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.
```

([Full Terminal Output](http://pastebin.com/CPqYh1gH))

[image: Output PDF]

Having skipped past `\setmainfont`, it seems to interpret the argument string as page content?

Comment: Your system is older, there the optional argument can't go at the end, move `[ItalicFont = sorts_mill_goudy-italic.otf, BoldFont = texgyrepagella-bold.otf ]`directly after `\setmainfont`.

Comment: lol Awesome, thanks. Once I'm able to test on OS X as well, I'll mark this as the answer. You could copy it as an answer, or if you don't I will.

Comment: Fedora 20 is obsolete. (Even Fedora 21 is, I just discovered, obsolete since the end of October.) You should definitely update the OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your system is older, there the optional argument can't go at the end, move `[ItalicFont = sorts_mill_goudy-italic.otf, BoldFont = texgyrepagella-bold.otf ]` directly after `\setmainfont`.